# Movie where a boy is searching for mysterious girl he’d seen either in a dream or once in real life

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

It’s some movie (maybe Disney) where a boy or old man is searching for this magical woman he’d seen either in a dream or once in real life. He goes to visit her mother and somehow upsets her. All I remember is the girl finding him and saying “you’ve upset my mother.” It was definitely strange, I think they were blonde???

Sorry, this is all I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, what was magical about the woman?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Answer (score 3):

**Possibly *Franklyn* (2008)**

Definitely not Disney, but *[Franklyn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0893402/)* is definitely strange, and it fits the bill, at least mostly.

[image]

There are several overlapping narratives, with most taking place in modern-day London, though one takes place in a strange, steampunky city where everyone wears masks.

One narrative follows the young man Milo, who is devastated after his fiancé left him just before their wedding. He runs into a childhood girl friend (who is a redhead, not a blonde, see picture below).

[image]

He then visits her mother, who becomes very upset, because this childhood friend

> was never anything but imaginary.

I'm not sure about the "you upset your mother" quote, however, so it might be another movie you're looking for, but I thought it worth mentioning for the similarities (and it is a great movie).